Почему бот выдает такую ошибку aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound: Chat not found
до этого все работало, вроде ничего не менял и теперь ругается. Название чата записано как CHANNEL_USERNAME = '@название'. бот состоит в группе и является администратором
import logging, time
from config import TOKEN, CHANNEL_USERNAME
from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from Keyboards import reply_keyboards as kb
from Handlers.Admin_handlers import users

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
async def check_channel_subscription(user_id: int, channel_username: str):
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=channel_username, user_id=user_id)
    if member.status in (types.ChatMemberStatus.MEMBER, types.ChatMemberStatus.ADMINISTRATOR, types.ChatMemberStatus.CREATOR):
        return True
    else:
        return False

async def process_start_command(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    is_subscribed = await check_channel_subscription(user_id, CHANNEL_USERNAME)
    if is_subscribed:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_full_name = message.from_user.full_name
        logging.info(f'{user_id=} {user_full_name=} {time.asctime()}')
        users.add(message.from_user.id)
        await message.answer(f"Привет, {user_full_name}", reply_markup=kb.keyboard_start)
        await state.set_state('choice')
    else:
        await message.answer("Для использования бота необходимо подписаться на группу.", reply_markup=kb.keyboard_sub)


def register_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(process_start_command, commands=['start'])```


Ты в chat_id передаёшь channel_username, передавай сам chat_id группы
